# Attempted to sync object 00k5b00000OlMOt which was previously synced in this transaction

Tags: error, quote, quotelineitem

When clicking "Start Sync" on a Quote under an Opportunity, we get this error:

"Attempted to sync object 00k5b00000OlMOt which was previously synced in this transaction"

The Opportunity previously had a quote synced under it, but that quote is no longer synced to it. But now, we're not able to sync the new one because we get this error. (also, I can tell by the prefix on the returned ID "00k" that this object is an opportunityLineItem, but it never gets inserted -- if you navigate to the ID in Salesforce after you get this error, the record doesn't exist)

I have looked around the web and there seems to be little information or documentation on this error.

Also, I have printed out debug logs for this, and there is no Exception given -- which to me is the craziest part. This is a Salesforce error, and yet Salesforce is not returning an Exception in the debug log with a trace line number. How are you supposed to debug this without that? (also, we know that no managed packages are consuming it, ie hiding it in the debug logs)

If anyone has any ideas or experience with this please let me know, it is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:

I met with Salesforce support and we turned off all custom logic that could impact the syncing process, and still we receive the error, so it seems to be related to the standard syncing process. They have contacted their Tier 3 team for further assistance.

Comment: Hi @Cory_16, did you manage to get resolution of your issue?

Comment: @user36778 No, I'm still in contact with Salesforce support regarding the issue

Comment: I will be keen to know the root cause once you hear back from them.